# Me'am Lo'ez on not beginning a new mesechta on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, rosh-chodesh-new-month

It is brought down by the Me'am Lo'ez to Vayikra (page 64) that it is customary not to begin learning a new mesechta on Rosh Chodesh.  The footnote gives as a source "Tur; Hagah; Taanis 32; Yoreh Deah 179."  First of all, is this custom still practiced today?  Also, what does he mean by "Taanis 32," since the gemara in Taanis only has 31 daf?  And which Tur or Hagah is he referring to?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a scriptable Daf Yomi calendar around?  You can try to find out when that last happened.  It should happen 1.3 times per cycle, on average.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is the custom practiced today?

The [רמ"א יו"ד סי' קע"ט](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Yoreh_Deah.179.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) סעיף ב [as understood by the פתחי תשובה יו"ד רמ"ה ס"ק ה] writes that our minhag is to start a new מסכת even on Rosh Chodesh.

> Also, what does he mean by "Taanis 32," since the gemara in Taanis only has 31 daf?

The correct version would be "ל (עמוד) ב". It seems to be a printing error.  On [Tannis 30b Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Taanit.30b.8?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) calculates when Moshe went up to get the second Luchos, which seems to come out on Rosh Chodesh. See גבורת ארי *ibid.* for a discussion and different opinions.

> And which Tur or Hagah is he referring to?

The Tur and [רמ"א](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.179.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) in יו"ד סי' קע"ט סעיף ב.